# argparse write results into a file

Tags: python, command-line, argparse

I am trying to learn how to convert .py code into command line with argparse(). Below is my testing-learning script. I can't figure out how to write the output into a file. I try two scenarios:

1. I use `parser.add_argument('out_file', type= argparse.FileType('w'))`, which gives follwoing error: *"coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found"*. And my understanding is that a file is already opened for writing.
2. Or I use `in_file = open(in_file, "r")`, and get *AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'*, which means it sees my input for **out_file** variable as a string, and not as a file where it should write a result.

I would appreciate any help in resolving the issues.

```
import csv
import argparse
import numpy as np  

def TESTFun(x_center, y_center, in_file, out_file):
    #in_file = open(in_file, "r")
    out_file = open(out_file, "w")
    f= np.genfromtxt(("\t".join(i) for i in csv.reader(in_file)),
                    delimiter = "\t", 
                    dtype = int)
    summ = x_center + y_center + f
    return out_file.write(str(summ) + "\n")
    out_file.close()

def ToCommandLine():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="This is a command to test")
    parser.add_argument('in_file',  type= argparse.FileType('r'))   #nargs='?'
    parser.add_argument('out_file', type= argparse.FileType('w'))
    parser.add_argument('-x_center', type= float, required= True)
    parser.add_argument('-y_center',  type= float, required= True)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    TESTFun(args.x_center, args.y_center, args.in_file, args.out_file)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ToCommandLine()


TESTFun(1, 4, "test.txt", "outtest.txt")
```

Answer (score 2):

Next time post the full stack, and specifically where the error happened - this will immediately show where, and probably what, the error is. I'm guessing here:

```
#in_file = open(in_file, "r")
```

and the same for out file:

```
out_file = open(out_file, "r")
```

The way `type= argparse.FileType` works is it **opens the file for you**. You're attempting to open an open file - remove those two lines, and use `args.in_file` and `args.out_file` directly as file descriptors.

The advantage of using a `FileType` rather than a string you open yourself is that `argparse` will check for errors on opening and let you know in a nicely printed way if there was trouble opening a file.

Answer (score 0):

You have set the type of `in_file` and `out_file` as a "File Object". Set it to `str` and pass the path to the file with the file name in the command line as the relevant argument.

```
import csv
import argparse
import numpy as np  

def TESTFun(x_center, y_center, in_file, out_file):
    in_file = open(in_file, "r")
    out_file = open(out_file, "w")
    f= np.genfromtxt(("\t".join(i) for i in csv.reader(in_file)),
                    delimiter = "\t", 
                    dtype = int)
    summ = x_center + y_center + f
    return out_file.write(str(summ) + "\n")
    out_file.close()

def ToCommandLine():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="This is a command that enables to visualize GOs")
    parser.add_argument('in_file', type=str, required= True)   # Enter the file path here
    parser.add_argument('out_file', type=str, required= True)  # Enter the file path here
    parser.add_argument('-x_center', type= float, required= True)
    parser.add_argument('-y_center',  type= float, required= True)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    TESTFun(args.x_center, args.y_center, args.in_file, args.out_file)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ToCommandLine()


TESTFun(1, 4, "test.txt", "outtest.txt")
```